# Characters Being Added To List<String>

Tags: java, android, string, list, stringbuilder

I have a List called dbData and two StringBuilders called infoSB and historySB. I've debugged my project and the two StringBuilders have all the data they are supposed to have, but for some reason it also adds some random characters to the data. All I've done to add the data is the code below:

```
dbData.add(infoSB.toString());
dbData.add(historySB.toString());
```

The characters being added are [ ] and ,

Has anyone ran into this before and know how to keep it from doing this?

UPDATE: Here is how I'm getting the data and assigning it to the StringBuilder.

```
JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
double altitudeData = json_data.getDouble("altitude");
double altitudeInFeet = altitudeData * 3.281;
historySB.append("Altitude: " + df.format(altitudeInFeet) + "ft\n");
```

Comment: Please show us the data.

Comment: {"longitude":"-86.642","latitude":"34.72533333333333","speed":"0.51444444","heading":"281","altitude":"190.8048"}

Comment: How did those characters end up there in the first place? I would correct the source that is generating these than handle them in a non-standard way on the receiving side.

Comment: I have changed my question to match what I have recently found when debugging my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these characters at the beginning and end of the string, and is the a comma somewhere in the middle? This is what the `toString`method of `List` is meant to do.

If you have a list of three elements

1. "car"
2. "van"
3. "bike"

Then the list will create the following string `[car, van, bike]`. The `[]` denote the beginning and end of the list, and commas denote the boundary between elements.

If you just want to concatenate strings then either use the `+` operator or a `StringBuilder` / `StringBuffer`.

eg.

```
String data = infoSB + historySB;
```

Comment: Yes, but what about `dbData`?

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. The extra characters are being produced by the `List` class when you turn it into a string.

Comment: Is this in the Java 7 API somewhere? I've been looking for it to read up on it but haven't found it yet.

Comment: toString methods generally aren't documented, but `[x0, x1, ..., xn-1]` is standard method for printing out a list in most languages.

Comment: Sorry misread your original post. I was able to fix the problem by looping through the list and adding it to my adapter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**-** First Check your `data source`, does they carry some sort of odd characters you are receiving.

**-** I hope what those `StringBuilder` holds are not `JSON`, i suspected it cause you are getting `[]` and `,` in your StringBuilders , so if it does you need to parse them first and then need to retrieve the specific Data you want....

**-** You can avoid any dangling whitespaces using `trim()` method

**Eg:**

```
dbData.add(infoSB.toString().trim());
dbData.add(historySB.toString().trim());
```

**///////////////////Edited Part///////////////////**

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
String altitudeData = json_data.getString("altitude");
double altitudeInFeet = Double.parseDouble(altitudeData) * 3.281;
historySB.append("Altitude: " + df.format(altitudeInFeet) + "ft\n");
```

Comment: When I debugged my code I checked the data inside infoSB and historySB on the lines right before I add them to the dbData and it does not contain the odd characters. The original source is JSONObject but as I'm parsing the data it's turning the data into doubles then adding them to the StringBuilder. Therefore it is no longer a JSONObject and the characters are not there. The characters are not present before the lines I showed in my question.

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted Ok try it this way..... don't turn your data into doubles... just parse it and take that data in form of String itself... on your requirement of a specific field to be of double type, then convert it.

Comment: The IDE doesn't seem to like that. I'll update the question with the code to show you what I have.